# Create ts object from weekly data

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
            Value
2002-09-01  0.4
2002-09-08  0.2
...............
2017-10-08  0.6
2017-10-15  0.5
```

Only the months of September and October are represented in the dataframe, and for October only the days of October 1-15 are ever included, so each year from 2002 to 2017 has a month and a half of data.

I now need to convert these values to a `ts` object.

I am attempting to do so like this:

```
t = ts(df$Value, frequency = 7, start = as.Date('2002-09-01'), end = as.Date('2017-10-15')
```

but this returns:

`invalid time series parameters specified`

Is this because October only has 15 days maybe?

Comment: I think you need to install packages that handle irregular time series.

Comment: I believe the `zoo` package supports irregular ts. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have

```
tt <- c(seq(as.Date("2002-09-01"), length = 7, by = 7), 
        seq(as.Date("2003-09-01"), length = 7, by = 7))
x <- 1:14
```

Then we could represent this as this zoo series:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(x, tt)
```

The dates here are not regularly spaced but if you had to force it into a regularly spaced ts series then assuming there are 7 points each year one way would be:

```
xser <- ts(setNames(x, tt), start = 2002, freq = 7)
```

This will represent the 7 points in year y using times of y, y + 1/7, ..., y + 6/7.  We have used the dates as names just so you can still relate each point to its date.

Comment: `z <- as.zoo(x, tt)` results in `Error in Ops.Date(delta, frequency) : * not defined for "Date" objects`?

Comment: Sorry. That should be zoo, not as.zoo. will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most time series libraries require the data to be evenly sampled for the given periods.

One thing to do is impute those values, i.e. replace the missing values with mean of last three periods. I recommend this [Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245615/how-to-fill-in-missing-data-in-time-series) for some ideas and also the library `imputeTS`.